# ASP.NET Core Web API (2.1.4) project results in HTTP 502.5 Error with error code 0x80070005

Tags: asp.net-core-2.1

I have tried to run my project on a server provided by someone else for some time now and after going through a lot of troubleshooting documents I'm at a spot where I don't know what to try next.
For debugging purposes I have created a plain, empty project (with just the default "values controller") and deployed that and it too produces the error.

The following information is available to me:

1. HTTP Server Error: 502.5
2. Logfile is produced but is empty
3. System Log shows the follówing:

> Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/WEBSITE-NAME/API' with
>   physical root '' created process with commandline
>   'E:\HostingSpaces\customer-folder\website-name\wwwroot\api\tu-test-api.exe
>   'but failed to get its status, ErrorCode = '0x80070005'.

I have tried different deployment types and all produce the same error. e.g. framework dependent, which produces a DLL. Then the error just stated that 'dotnet tu-test-api.dll' produces the error. But the codes and behavior is the same.

The server is a Windows 2008 R2 Server with IIS Express.

It has Microsoft .NET Core 2.1.4 WIndows Server Hosting installed.

The following three things are installed:

1. Microsoft .NET Core Runtime 2.1.4 (x64)
2. Microsoft .NET Core 2.1.4 - Windows Server Hosting
3. Microsoft .NET Core Runtime 2.1.4 (x86)

According to the Admin 
1. PATH variable is set correct
2. Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x64) is installed
3. After (2.) Bundle was repaired/reinstalled and server was rebooted

I'm a bit irritated because physical root is an empty string in the system logs. But I'm not sure what that means.

Any help on what to try next would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm assuming you don't have access to the server directly?

Comment: No, but I can email the admin to do stuff. Which we have done for about a week now and I'm out of ideas of what to try next. :(

Comment: Well, my first stab at debugging ASP.NET Core apps on the server is always to just start them up in a console window: `dotnet MyApp.dll`. If there's exceptions being thrown on startup, you'll see them there. Perhaps your admin can run this and then send you a copy of the console window afterwards. Assuming the app starts fine this way, then there's something wrong with IIS, usually involving the hosting bundle not being installed correctly.

Comment: to get some form of logging you'll need to modify the `web.config` file after publish  `<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\App.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />`  that might help you get a better error message at least.  Has the IIS server AppPool been properly set to "No Managed Code" etc?

Comment: Also, while you'll probably find some help here, this post is slightly off topic for stackoverflow.com and you might get a better answer from https://serverfault.com

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. As I've mentioned in the post, I have activated the logging feature and a log file is created but it is empty. Which seems to be the case with a lot of the "process didn't start"-errors.
I will ask about the AppPool, although the Microsoft Troubleshooting and Configuration pages state, that this is optional.